# Need help changing code

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to change my `NSTimer` code to to use `applicationSignificantTimeChange`

This is what I have right now.

Basically I want to change the timer, instead of changing every 5 seconds for example I want these textLabels to change at 12am every night anyone help me out?

h file

```
NSTimer *timer;

IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
```

m file

```
- (void)onTimer {

static int i = 0;

if ( i == 0 ) { 
textLabel.text = @"iphone app";
}

else if ( i == 1 ) {
textLabel.text = @" Great App!";
}

else if ( i == 2 ) {
textLabel.text = @" WOW!";
}

else {
textLabel.text = @" great application again!!";
i = -1;
}

i++;
}


timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check `initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` method of `NSTimer`? Click [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTimer) for more details

Comment: Yes and that didn't quite help anyway you could explain it to me please?